# How to privately send a message that is used by nothing but my app?

Tags: java, android, sms

I have this app that sends encrypted text messages to the specified phone number. When a message is received, it shows up in my app but also in any other SMS app I have installed. **I want to disable the global notification of the received text message.**

What I am trying to do is send an encrypted message as a regular text message and send the key to decrypt it as a private message that is not displayed in the chat log. My app should have some kind of notifier to know which incoming message is the key and which is the encrypted text.

I read about using a `localbroadcastmanager` but I had no luck getting that to work with my code setup. I also was not sure if the manager would be able to send messages to other phone numbers.

I can post code snippest if necessary, but I don't see a reason for that.
Thanks for your time and any help guys.

UPDATE: I have found some posts about using ports so that only my app will listen for messages coming in from the specified port and no other app will see the messages on that port. I have implemented a quick program to send a message to a port I chose, but the message still shows up in all messaging apps. Do ports do what I think they'll do? Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using data SMS for the key, possibly the message itself?

Comment: May you elaborate a bit on the data SMS part? Maybe share a link? I am not familiar with it. Thanks.